# Intellij Idea: Gradle sync cancelled even if it successful from command line

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, synchronization

I am opening a working Gradle project in Idea, but it is failing to sync. In the sync window it says Sync cancelled. I tried changing proxy settings, project SDK, reboot, killing gradle daemon forcefully, but no luck

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached: Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing Gradle JVM from settings.
In Maven project we can set project SDK, and it will be used for Maven build also.
But for Gradle we have to set it differently. Setting project SDK alone doesn't help as it is used only for project by Idea and not for Gradle.
Need to set the Gradle JVM to compatible JVM

1. Go to Settings
2. Search for **Gradle** under **Build Tools**
3. Set **Gradle JVM** to >=1.8